# profile email notifications: can CiviCRM indicate what information has changed?

Tags: profile, email

Members on our site can update their own profiles, using a custom profile that is set to send notification emails to administrators when an update is submitted.

The notification email contains all the data now in the profile -- but it would be great if the data that was *changed* was indicated by a different color, or maybe just some indication of which fields have a changed value.

I have no idea how CiviCRM handles versioning (if it even does), so I have no idea if this is even possible without significant custom development.

Anybody have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is *Logging*.

In the Civi menu, go to Administer > System Settings > Misc (Undelete, PDFs, Limits, Logging, Captcha, etc.)

Enable logging, and from then on all changes to contact records will be recorded. You can view them by visiting the "Change Log" tab on the contact summary screen.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's definitely useful, but not exactly what I'm after.  I have a couple of people who don't have access to the CiviCRM system but who maintain external systems and only get the notification emails.  The mails are complete, but it's hard for them to see immediately what's changed, so they have to review the entire record every time they get an update.

Are there any notification hooks for logging -- maybe only send email regarding the CHANGED data, instead of the whole profile?